# Debugging mobile Laravel REST API with PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, rest, phpstorm, xdebug

I have an iOS mobile application and REST API written in Laravel PHP.
My goal is to set a breakpoint in one of my API endpoints in PHP code in PhpStorm IDE, and using a mobile application hit that breakpoint and debug.

I have Xdebug installed and it's listening on port 9000.

If I run a built-in PHP Web Server using PhpStorm configuration, start listen to PHP Debug Connections and simply go to `http://localhost:9000/index.php` in Chrome browser, I do succeed to hit a breakpoint placed in that file.

But if I go to `http://localhost:9000/register` from the browser, I get 404.
Maybe I need to tell it to use my routes.php file?

What is my problem?

What are the steps to debug Laravel PHP REST API from a mobile application?

Comment: 1) *"I have Xdebug installed and it's listening on port 9000."* ?? Xdebug does not listen anything -- it's IDE/editor that listens for incoming debug connections as it's xdebug that makes them. 2) Where PHP is running -- same computer or VM/etc? Right now it all sounds wrong/weird (the website on 9000 port). I suggest to read/watch this first: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm and https://xdebug.org/docs/remote to get the proper idea of how it all works (as right now it/your setup all sounds messy to me)

Comment: @LazyOne PHP is running on the same computer. If not 9000, what port should I configure in the Run/Debug Configurations?

Comment: Anyone? Can someone please let me know briefly about the correct steps to debug PHP Rest API through web storm? (ports, debugger)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a route for /register ?
Have you tried to set a breakpoint in the controller method that is called by the "/register" ?
I work with Laravel and Visual Studio Code instead of PhpStorm but XDebug is the same doesn't matter which editor you use.

Comment: Yes, sure. The problem is that whenever I go to http://localhost:9000/register, I get 404, as if I don't have access to it.

Comment: This is my route to register: Route::post('register', array('uses' => 'UserRegistrationController@processUserRegistration'));

Comment: Have you tried in this way? 

Route::post('register', 'UserRegistrationController@processUserRegistration');

Comment: if refer to your comments with LazyOne I suggest you to check your php.ini file and experiment with the configuration of XDebug on your machine.
Below is part of my php.ini of my Mamp php 7.1.6 configuration:

[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port=9099 

; Recommended when using Symfony
xdebug.max_nesting_level=250

Comment: As you can see I set XDebug to listen at port 9099 and in my configuration work well. My Mamp ngix server listen to 8888

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In the meantime, I simply changed the port to 8080 and checked "use route script" to my routes.php in debug/run configuration window. It now stops at the first line of routes.php, but then says: "Class Route not found".